attempting to install libdeflate - "gcc versions older than 4.9 are no longer supported", but I'm using gcc 7.3
I am trying to install libdeflate in an python environment on a HPC using the following code
cd $tools_dir
git clone https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate.git
cd $tools_dir/libdeflate

module load cmake/3.29.3
cmake -B build && cmake --build build

I get the following error
 error: #error "gcc versions older than 4.9 are no longer supported"

But
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.0

I'm new to this so I am probably making a silly mistake but any help would be great
I have tried updating cmake but I think there is some issue with the path/directory I am using

When configure the project (cmake -B build in your case) CMake prints exact path to the compiler and its version. What is printed in your case?

@Tsyvarev
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ~/.conda/envs/snakemake-env/tools/libdeflate/build
I am working in the dir /libdeflate, which is where CMakeLists.txt is located

These are the last lines of the CMake output. Compiler path is printed near the beginning of that output. Look for the line like "Check for working C compiler"

what I sent is all I get with the cmake -B build command but when i use cmake . I get -- No build type selected; defaulting to Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped ....

So your project is configured with the compiler /usr/bin/cc which is a GNU compiler of version 4.8.5.
